# Slurm Versioning - 2.X and 1X

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, slurm

I would like to know where the difference between Slurm versions around `2.X.X` and `13-15.X` are.

The most detailed list I could find regarding versioning is here:
http://www.schedmd.com/#news

It seems that with Slurm version `2.6.1` another version named `13.12.0-pre1` came out.

However, nowhere is explained, how these two versions differ from each other.

While the version `13.X` is still under development (currently `15.X`), it seemed to have stopped for Slurm version `2.6.7`.

Are these two different versions compatible to each other? Are upgrades from `2.X` to `15.X` possible? Are these versions completely diffferent? And if so, in what do they differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Slurm version `2.X.X` are quite old versions and no longer supported. The last stable version is `14.11` and the next one should be `15.08`.

Slurm only support upgrades from up to two further versions, so is not possible to upgrade directly from `2.6.X` to `14.X` or `15.X`.

Slurm can work with up to **two major** different versions simultaneously. So you can have in the same cluster `14.03` and `15.08` but the controller and the database daemon should always be on the latest version.

The change from `2.6.7` to `13.x` was simply a change in the version numbering convention, to follow a `YEAR.MONTH` version name, and from that point the developers try to relase 2 versions a year.

Comment: Cheers! Exactly what I needed

Comment: More information on the reasons why they changed the numbering convention [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.distributed.slurm.devel/3979)